# Cauchy sequences: equivalent condition using minimum

Tags: proof-verification, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I have been trying to prove the following statement.

> Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and $\{s_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of elements of $X$. For $\varepsilon > 0$, consider the two sets
>   \begin{equation*}
> A_{\varepsilon} := \{ (m, n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} : d(s_n, s_m) > \varepsilon \} \quad \text{and} \quad B_{\varepsilon} := \{ \min \{n, m\} : (m, n) \in A_{\varepsilon} \}.
> \end{equation*}
>   The following are equivalent:
>
> 1. $\forall \, \varepsilon > 0$ the set $B_{\varepsilon}$ is finite, and
> 2. $\forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \quad \exists \, \overline{n} \in \mathbb{N} : \quad \forall \, n, m \geqslant \overline{n} \quad d(s_n, s_m) \leqslant \varepsilon$.

$\boxed{(1) \Rightarrow (2)}$ Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. By hypothesis, the set $B_{\varepsilon}$ is finite. Hence, there exists $\overline{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n < \overline{n}\ \forall \, n \in B_{\varepsilon}$. If $n, m \geqslant \overline{n}$, then we have $d(s_n, s_m) \leqslant \varepsilon$. Otherwise, it would be $\min \{n, m\} \in B_{\varepsilon}$, but this is absurd, because $\min \{n, m \} \geqslant \overline{n}$.

$\boxed{(2) \Rightarrow (1)}$ Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. By hypothesis, there exists $\overline{n} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $d(s_n, s_m) \leqslant \varepsilon\ \forall \, n, m \geqslant \overline{n}$. We can prove that $n < \overline{n}\ \forall \, n \in B_{\varepsilon}$. Let $n$ be a natural number such that $n \geqslant \overline{n}$. For any $m \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $m \geqslant \overline{n}$ or $m < \overline{n}$. If $m \geqslant \overline{n}$, then $d(s_n, s_m) \leqslant \varepsilon$ and $n \notin B_{\varepsilon}$; if $m < \overline{n}$, then $\min \{n, m\} = m$ and $n \notin B_{\varepsilon}$. Therefore, we have $n < \overline{n}\ \forall \, n \in B_{\varepsilon}$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I haven't looked at your proof, but I think saying: $(2) \iff \forall \varepsilon>0\;\;\; \text{$A_{\varepsilon}$ is finite} \iff \forall \varepsilon>0\;\;\; \text{$B_{\varepsilon}$ is finite}$ is fine

Comment: @user160738 I don't think the implication $\forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \ A_{\varepsilon}$ is finite $\Rightarrow (2)$ is true. For example, take $\{ 1/n \}_{n \geqslant 1}$. If $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, then all pairs $(n, m) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = 1$ and $m > 2$ belong to $A_{\varepsilon}$. In fact, it is true $\forall \, \varepsilon > 0 \ A_{\varepsilon}$ is finite iff the sequence is constant.

Comment: Ohhh, you are right, I was careless. I'm sorry if it confused you in any way; I think both of your arguments are fine. It's matter of style, but in the second argument, you could write stuff like: suppose that $n\ge \overline{n}$ and $n\in B_{\varepsilon}$. Then there must be a pair of integers $i,j\ge n\ge \overline{n}$ such that $d(s_i,s_j)>\varepsilon$ (i.e. $(s_i,s_j)\in A_{\varepsilon}$. This contradicts definition of $\overline{n}$, so if $n\in B_{\varepsilon}$ then $n<\overline{n}$.

Comment: @user160738 Thank you for your comment